# Drupal 7 site homepage not inserting metatag Page title into title element

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, title, meta-tags

Every other page on the site functions in such a way that the content entered into a page's meta tag page title field is inserted into that page's title element, but for some reason this isn't working for the homepage. I think it is using a previous description and won't update to the new one. I found [this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/1293214) which seemed to be in relation to my problem but the main solutions didn't solve the problem.

Adding the PHP below into the bottom of the homepage node didn't solve the problem:

```
print render ($page['content']['metatags'])
```

or

```
print render ($content['metatags'])`
```

Has anyone else run into this problem and discovered another possible solution?

Comment: Have you set the `Global: Front page` metatags in `admin/config/search/metatags` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems complex to get to it's cause so easy... but you can try the following code in a template of your frontpage (or asking inside a more generic template file if it's frontpage with drupal_is_front_page function):

```
print render(metatag_metatags_view('global:frontpage', array()));
```

That will print your metatags as far as I know.

If that does not work then you should debug every line of that function (metatag_metatags_view)... if you have access to the code of course... it's not pretty thing to do but there lies the root to your  problem.

Hope that helps!